# Gmod Expression 2 Text Commands

Tags: garrys-mod

I am playing Garry's Mod and I'm trying to make an e2 chip that allows me to add guns to a price list with for example "!name *store name*" and then "+ *AK47- $500*". This is what I have so far and I can't seem to figure out how to make the screen say what I say!

```
    @name manual prices screen
@inputs Screen:wirelink
@outputs 
@persist A:array Cname:string [M1 M2 M3 M4]:array
@trigger 
runOnChat(1)

Say = owner():lastSaid():explode(" ")

if(Say[1,string] == "+")
{
    chatClk(owner())
        hideChat(1),Screen:writeString("Prices:" ,1,3,100,5,0)
}


if(Say[1,string] == "!name")
{
    Name = owner():lastSaid():explode(" ")(Say[2,string])
    print(Name:name() + " added")
 M4[M4:count()+1,entity] = Player
 Screen[2041] = 1
}

interval(100)
```

Comment: Why tag 4 different languages?

Comment: Because no one will see it otherwise, do you know how to fix it?

Comment: Instead of helping why did everyone just edit the post..